# Assigning color depending upon data count in a dictionary in django

Tags: python, django, dictionary

From db I am getting below data. Then I am preparing a python dictionary from this data. Now I want to assign each row a color, but there is a condition. If a codezone is associated with multiple zips then that row will get grey color. The zones which are associated with single zip those will get some other color. How can I prepare the dictionary from the below data.

```
+----------+-------+--------------+
| codeZone | ZipCd | Longitude    |
+----------+-------+--------------+
| Zone 81  | 13064 | -76.70275100 |
| Zone 81  | 13143 | -76.73114800 |
| Zone 81  | 13146 | -76.76016600 |
| Zone 72  | 13148 | -76.78488000 |
| Zone 72  | 13165 | -76.87704600 |
| Zone 50  | 14011 | -78.28090700 |
| Zone 50  | 14020 | -78.19062500 |
| Zone 50  | 14058 | -78.15694600 |
| Zone 50  | 14098 | -78.37735300 |
| Zone 50  | 14103 | -78.38546900 |
| Zone 50  | 14125 | -78.27249300 |
| Zone 50  | 14143 | -78.08089700 |
| Zone 50  | 14411 | -78.20223900 |
| Zone 81  | 14413 | -76.98321400 |
| Zone 60  | 14414 | -77.73609300 |
| Zone 50  | 14416 | -77.98543200 |
| Zone 72  | 14418 | -77.21132300 |
| Zone 14  | 14420 | -77.92950200 |
| Zone 50  | 14422 | -78.07160700 |
| Zone 60  | 14423 | -77.84307800 |
| Zone 71  | 14424 | -77.30122500 |
| Zone 70  | 14425 | -77.31024000 |
| Zone 61  | 14427 | -78.04682800 |
| Zone 16  | 14428 | -77.81500000 |
+----------+-------+--------------+
```

my data looks something likr this

[{'zone': 1, 'zip': 1, 'spec': a}, {'zone': 1, 'zip': 2, 'spec': m}, {'zone': 2, 'zip': 3, 'spec': pC}]

Now zone 1 is associated with zip 1 and zip 2. Zone 2 is associated with only zip 3. So I want to assing a 4th key(i.e color) to the dictioanry, which will based upon the count of zone(if more than one zone then grey color). so for zip 1 and zip 2 the color will be grey. For zip 3 anyother color.

Answer (score 2):

Count the zipcodes per zone, then include that information in your mapping:

```
from collections import defaultdict

zipcount = defaultdict(set)
for zone, zip, longitude in datarows:
    zipcount[zone].add(zip)

# Create the output dictionary
output_dict = {}
for zone, zip, longitude in datarows:
    count = len(zipcount[zone])
    # adjust output dictionary based on the count (1 or more)
```

Comment: @sandeep You have to be more specific than this. What exactly is not working? What is the error?

Comment: @sandeep: I had to guess at what your data structure is looking like, because you didn't include code. 'not working for me' tells me absolutely nothing, I am afraid.

Comment: In the above I have just showed 3 cols from the db, but in real there are 15-17 cols coming from the db. So I am running a forloop considering 3 cols then its showing "too many values to unpack".

Comment: @sandeep: I was using tuple unpacking (assuming each row only has 3 elements). Use `for row in datarows:` then (no tuple unpacking) and pluck the `zone` and `zipcode` values from that.

Comment: my data looks something likr this

[{'zone': 1, 'zip': 1, 'spec': a}, {'zone': 1, 'zip': 2, 'spec': m}, {'zone': 2, 'zip': 3, 'spec': pC}]

Now zone 1 is associated with zip 1 and zip 2. Zone 2 is associated with only zip 3. So I want to assing a 4th key(i.e color) to the dictioanry, which will based upon the count of zone(if more than one zone then grey color). so for zip 1 and zip 2 the color will be grey. For zip 3 anyother color.